# PY: Url Encode without variable name

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to url encode list without variables names?
for example 
q=['with space1', 'with space2']

into 
qescaped=['with%20space1', 'with%20space2']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [urllib.quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) together with [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
import urllib
q = ['with space1', 'with space2']
qescaped = map(urllib.quote, q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays list comprehensions are the Pythonic way to do this:

```
q = [ 'with space1', 'with space2' ]
qescaped = [ urllib.quote(u) for u in q ]
```

Often you do not even have to build that list but can use the generator itself instead:

```
qescapedGenerator = (urllib.quote(u) for u in q)
```

(This saves memory and, in case you do not need all elements, also computation time.)

A lot of receivers can process on generators as well:

```
urlsInLines = '\n'.join(urllib.quote(u) for u in q)
```

```
for escapedUrl in (urllib.quote(u) for u in q):
    print escapedUrl
```

And if any receive needs a list after all, just putting `list()` around the generator creates the list anyway.